# why doesn't the servlet retrieve the part ? It shows null as the file name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, multipartform-data

The *html* snippet sends a `post` request to a `servlet` named *servlet*. The request is of type `multipart/form-data`.But servlet finds nothing and prints null for the name of the part I try to retrieve. Why is that ?

```
<form method="post" action="servlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" value="browse" name="FileShared" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

---

```
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    //String fileName = request.getPart("FileShared").getName(); 
    // Throws a nullpointer exception if I don't comment the above statement
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    //writer.println(fileName);
    Collection<Part> c = request.getParts();
    Iterator i = c.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        writer.println("Inside while loop"); // This statement never gets printed
        writer.println(i.next());
    }
    writer.println("outside while loop"); // Only this statement gets printed
}
```

Comment: BalusC wrote an excellent answer for a [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) concerning File Upload using Serlvet 3.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use Servlet 3.0 `HttpServletRequest#getParts()` method , then you must annotate your servlet with `@MultipartConfig`.

**Example :**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/SampleServlet"})
@MultipartConfig
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

}
```

Comment: How can it be done in case of Servlet < 3.0 to be specific Servlet 2.5